# How can I make my friend's electric violin sound even more electric (almost like a synth)? (example sound provided)

Tags: sound-design, sound-effects, live-sound

I have a friend who owns a Yamaha YEV-5 5-string electric violin.
Example unedited sound here:

He wants to figure out the effects to make it sound practically synth-like, as in this recording here:

(jump to 1m12s for the violin).
But, he wants that tone live, not in a recording room.

I know it needs very heavy compression and EQ out most of the highs. Is there anything else I can do to increase the 'synth'-y electric sound? I'm not a professional sound engineer so I'm not sure what other tools I can use to make that sound, live.

Comment: I think it's very likely there is little being done to change the sound of the violin in the video. It definitely doesn't sound like "most of the highs" were EQed out. They're still there. Maybe a bit of EQ just to make it nice sounding, a bit of compression, and a bit of reverb. Nothing exotic.

Comment: @ToddWilcox I play acoustic violin / viola and I have handled electric violins before. While they do sound artificial, good e-violins do not normally sound like a synth. There is a LARGE difference between 'raw' e-violin sound versus the second video's "produced" sound.

I had borrowed my friend's electric violin and was able to come fairly close to the 'produced' sound in the second video just with massive compression and reducing the highs. I suppose a touch of overdrive or saturation is needed, but I don't have the tools for it.

Comment: Echoing Todd, that second example doesn't sound like a synth at all, just a DI output from the instrument with delay and reverb.  Nothing special going on other than the player's interesting technique.

Comment: @DataProcessing That second video sound absolutely does not sound like DI output. Again, speaking from limited, but personal, experience of these instruments. As artificial as e-violins sound, they do not sound that way (in video 2) without significant processing.

Comment: Didn't you come to this group to speak to people with more experience than you?  Or only to push your own views?

Comment: @DataProcessing Unless your speakers are faulty an e-violin does not sound so synth-like out of the box, there is _definitely_ EQ and compression. I used a friend's electric violin, and searched for several sound samples and recordings of e-violin online. Confirmed by using sound samples and EQing them. I also build pickups and I play violin/viola, so I might not be a pro sound engineer but I have a very good ear for frequencies related to strings. I was hoping people might have insight into plugins or specific EQ settings that lead to that sort of synth-y tone.

Comment: @DataProcessing As it stands, a band-pass filter and just massive compression have got me very close. And I suspect the rest might be autotune, which I don't have. He's doing a lot of 'vibrato' but you hear none of it on the output. So I'll see what my friend can manage.

Comment: Boloar - I can get my electric violin to sound just like that with a little reverb, and the presence rolled off a bit on my 5150 amp. Nothing else needed.